# Forms: How to add dropdown choice at the end of an input text field?

Tags: javascript, forms, select, input

I am building a HTML form for a subdomain maker. I am not great in using javascript, so my question may be silly. But I ask here as this is the place that has given me the best answers yet :-)

The subdomain will consist of {users-input}.{oneofmanypredefined.domains}

The user will be able to make a subdomain where they can 
1) enter any value (a-z,0-9,-) in a text field, 
and 
2) then choose what predefined main domain they want to add the subdomain to.

I have made it work now by using a input text field + a select options. This way I need to mix them into one hidden field on the next page (form action="nextpage.php")

**Possible solution 1:**
Is there a way where I can make ONE text field has one part that is like a normal text field, and then one part that is a dropdown, but with the same id and name?

I tried to post an image, but need more reputations: http://bildr.no/image/cSsyNWdQ.jpeg

I have googled and searched here, but not found any solution for this. It may because there is none, but at least I can ask :-)

The reason I ask is if this exists, then it will help me save time redoing all javascript and all other code built on this one input field.

**Possible solution #2:** Is there is a good way to use javascript to combine "on the fly" a value entered into a text field + a value chosen in a select, so I can use that combined value to enter into all javascript. So that every time I write in a text field, or make a new select choice, the javascript updates on the fly?

Comment: You even don't need to make the hidden input field. On the server-side you can combine the two values simply.

Comment: #1: there's nothing out-of0the-box. To achieve this, you would have to write some javascript to prompt the domains when user inputs the subdomain (anything and a dot). #2: can use the submit event of the form to concatenate both values and insert it into a hidden field.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisBenseler. However I need to get the combined value before I hit any button. Right now I have made it tp POST the values to the next page, and on the next page I have combined the values into one. But this makes the validator on the first page only validate one of the values. I need to validate both combined as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible solution #2 is likely to be realistic.
This is an init state:

```
var combined_value = '';
var input_field = $('#subdomain'); // <input type="text" id="subdomain" ... >
var select_field = $('#domain_list'); // <select id="domain_list" ... >
```

Then two onchange events can be defined:

```
input_field.change(update_combined_value);
select_field.change(update_combined_value);

function update_combined_value() {
    combined_value = input_field.val() + select_field.val();
}
```

Thus after every change the variable `combined_value` contains the whole subdomain.

Comment: Thank you. I'll test this as soon as I am back to my main computer :-)

Comment: I got some time now. Made this fiddle. This works :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/13asc1dt/4/

Comment: I can upvote you as soon as I get enough reputations. I need 15 to be able to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and the (HTML5 required attribute), you can use this:

```
<form action="anything.html" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" id="field1" name="par1" required  />
    <input type="text" id="field2" name="par2" required />

    <input type="text" id="willbehidden" name="concatpars" />

    <button>send</button>
</form>

$("form").on("submit", function() {
    $("#willbehidden").val( $("#field1").val() + $("#field2").val() )
});
```

JSFIDDLE here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisbenseler/6xw3f8mq/

Form is posted only if the first 2 inputs are not blank.